# form.addOrientationListener(new ActionListener() not being called on keyboard open

Tags: codenameone

Form codenameone 3.4 onward this issue seems to exists, previous version it works fine.

When keyboard is open on rotation of the tablet form portrait to landscape the screen is not displayed fully. In this the form.addOrientationListener(new ActionListener() {} not being called.

What is issue on new version??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fix for a bug. Orientation listener was designed to only fire on orientation changes and you relied on behavior that was incorrect.

What you are looking for is `addSizeChangedListener()`. Notice that if you are seeing artifacts on Android related to the virtual keyboard that might be related to a different issue.